# How to Append data in While loop into Empty DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe which has 5 columns.

```
Df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['userId','movieId','rating','timestamp','genres'])
```

I have this function

```
def Main():

    flag = 0
    while(flag <=99):
        data1 = pickRandomMovies()
        data2 = usersToMovies(data1)
        if len(data2) < 6:
            data2 = data1
        else:
            flag +=1
            data3 = commonUsers(data2)
            #append all values of data3 here to new dataframe
            df_new.append(data3)

            findingRatings(data3)
```

```
>>data3
userId  movieId  rating   timestamp                      genres
 27       60      3.0     962685387         Adventure|Children|Fantasy
 103      60      4.0     1431968436        Adventure|Children|Fantasy
 160      60      2.0     971619579         Adventure|Children|Fantasy
 27      1210     4.0     962684909         Action|Adventure|Sci-Fi
 103     1210     3.5     1431957028        Action|Adventure|Sci-Fi
 160     1210     5.0     971113953         Action|Adventure|Sci-Fi
```

i want to append all values of data3 into new dataframe in every iteration.

Comment: you can initialize a new dataframe e.g. `df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['whatever'])` and then you can use `df_new.append(data3)`. If the collumns are the same then this will be okay.

Comment: How does the data in `data3` looks like? Could you print out `data3` so its easier to see?

Comment: @geoph9 i have tried this but new dataframe comes empty

Comment: @Jan33 data3 is printed.

Comment: can you share the code you have tried for which you got empty dataframe

Comment: @ArunJose_Intel i have posted the code of Main(). In data3 another dataframe is coming with same column names at each iteration.

Comment: see my answer ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code to

```
def Main():

    flag = 0
    while(flag <=99):
        data1 = pickRandomMovies()
        data2 = usersToMovies(data1)
        if len(data2) < 6:
            data2 = data1
        else:
            flag +=1
            data3 = commonUsers(data2)
            #append all values of data3 here to new dataframe
            df_new=df_new.append(data3)

            findingRatings(data3)
```

`df_new.append(data3)` only appends the value it does not assign the value it should be done explicitly by `df_new=df_new.append(data3)`